# Is it ok for MySQL to always use 18-25% of Memory (I have 2 GB Ram)?

Tags: mysql, memory, mysql-8.0, debugging

I have MySQL 8 in my Server with Ram of 2GB. And MySQL is always using 18-25% of Ram even when everything is off. Is it normal? If not then plz let me know how to debug it. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's normal. Memory usage is determined by various configuration parameters, some of which are shared (e.g. innodb_buffer_pool_size), while others are per thread.